# Post Request in Kotlin

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, httprequest

I'm trying to do a post request in Android Studio written in Kotlin

I'm posting a JSON object to our server and then the server is returning a JSON object back. But what I'm doing here is decoding the response body as a string and then converting it into the data structure we need. I'm sure there is a better and simpler way to do what I need done.

My current code works but the major issue I'm having is formatting the string if our objects have nested objects which is why I want to figure out a better way to turn the response body into a json object.

I'm not too familiar with many request libraries for kotlin but I have looked into okhttp3 but I'm not sure how to post a json object, attach headers and decode the response body into a json object.

I know for okhttp3 I need to convert the json object to a string to post other than that I'm lost.

Breakdown of what's needed:

1. Post JSON Object To Server
2. Send Headers With Post Request
3. Decode Response Body into JSON Object/ Kotlin Equivalent
4. Simplify What I'm Trying to Do if Possible

This is the current code I have

```
private fun postRequestToGetDashboardData() {
        val r = JSONObject()
        r.put("uid", muid)
        r.put("token", mtoken)
        SendJsonDataToServer().execute(r.toString());
    }
```

```
inner class SendJsonDataToServer :
        AsyncTask<String?, String?, String?>() {

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            if (result.equals(null)) {
                val t = Toast.makeText(this@Home, "No devices to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
                t.show()
            } else {
                intentForUnique.putExtra("FirstEndpointData", result)
                var list = handleJson(result)
                adapter.submitList(list)
                dashboardItem_list.adapter = adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dashboardItem_list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): String? {
            val JsonDATA = params[0]!!
            var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection? = null
            var reader: BufferedReader? = null

            try {
                val url = URL("URL");
                urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection;
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", mtoken);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                val writer: Writer =
                    BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(JsonDATA);
                writer.close();
                val inputStream: InputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                var inputLine: String? = reader.readLine()
                if (inputLine.equals("null")) {
                    return null
                } else {
                    return inputLine
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Connection Failed", ex);
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error closing stream", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null
        }
    }
```

```
private fun handleJson(jsonString: String?): ArrayList<SensorData> {
        val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)
        val list = ArrayList<SensorData>()
        var x = 0
        while (x < jsonArray.length()) {
            val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)
            list.add(
                SensorData(
                    jsonObject.getInt("deviceId"),
//                    jsonObject.getString("deviceName"),
                    jsonObject.getInt("battery"),
                    jsonObject.getString("dateTime"),
                    jsonObject.getInt("airValue"),
                    jsonObject.getInt("waterValue"),
                    jsonObject.getInt("soilMoistureValue"),
                    jsonObject.getInt("soilMoisturePercent")
                )
            )
            x++
        }
        return list
    }
```

So the json data being returned back is an array of this structure (our backend is written in Go)

```
type Device struct {
    DeviceID            int                `bson:"deviceId" json:"deviceId"` 
    Battery             int                `bson:"battery" json:"battery"`
    DateTime            time.Time          `bson:"dateTime" json:"dateTime"`
    AirValue            int                `bson:"airValue" json:"airValue"`
    WaterValue          int                `bson:"waterValue" json:"waterValue"`
    SoilMoistureValue   int                `bson:"soilMoistureValue" json:"soilMoistureValue"`
    SoilMoisturePercent int                `bson:"soilMoisturePercent" json:"soilMoisturePercent"`
}
```

Comment: If you're going Kotlin I suggest you look into coroutines and Ktor instead of AsyncTask and OkHttp. They will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks